# AttributeError with Scikit-Learn 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' even though I've verified the input is a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, k-means

When running this function

```
def evaluate_performance(self, data):

        data = np.array(data)
        print(data.shape[0])

        if self.cluster_method == 'kmeans':
            predicted_labels = self.cluster_model.predict(data)
            score = silhouette_score(data, predicted_labels)
            print(f"Silhouette score: {score}")

        elif self.cluster_method == 'isolation_forest':
            predicted_scores = self.cluster_model.score_samples(data)
            score = silhouette_score(data, predicted_scores)
            print(f"Silhouette score: {score}")
```

I get this error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`

The data is accessed from a csv file in a separate function which returns the values attribute of a pandas data frame.

I used print statements to verify that the input data to the `.predict` is a numpy array and even got the value of `data.shape`, but I can't seem to figure out why this error persists.

Comment: can you show first 5 rows from data?

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili Sure: ```<bound method NDFrame.head of         Account ID     Timestamp  Device information  Operating system  App version  ...  User engagement  Ad interactions  User demographics  User behavior  External factors
0           4027.0  1.652864e+09                 1.0               3.0          5.0  ...              1.0              1.0               29.0            3.0               0.0
1           3955.0  1.671295e+09                 1.0               2.0          1.0  ...              1.0              0.0               59.0            2.0               1.0```

Comment: your data is not 2D Dataframe, maybe because do not work. convert NDFrame to Dataframe.

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili Thank you for your response, I tried this and verified that the data is in a Dataframe, but I still receive the same error :(

Comment: asumme, problem is in EDA, when you convert data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the methods of your class, but the [Silhouette reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) defines it this way:

```
sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels)
```

Thus your first condition looks nice, but the second one includes

```
score = silhouette_score(data, predicted_scores)
```

Putting scores here is weird, consider replacing it with labels.

Hope, it helps